# Is there anyway to speed up the reshape process in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I currently am working on reshaping python arrays into three dimensional numpy structure using`np.numpy`

For example, I use `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (1000, 7, 5))`

However, as row number of above code increases, the reshaping process consumes enormous time.

For example `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (1000, 9, 5))` increases the completion time by 2 hours.

I was wondering if there is a way to reduce to completion time without changing the reshape dimensions. Or another alternative way?

Thanks in advance.

Saul.

Comment: You may want to take a look at numba: https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: Increases up to what amount?

Comment: 2 hours. The issue is that reshaping takes huge time as the middle value increases.

Comment: For me it takes about 0.00002 seconds (from `x_train = np.arange(45000)`).

Comment: What is `x_train`? If it is already a numpy array the reshape should be very fast. If something else reshape first has to first do `np.array(x_train)`.  But (1000,7,5) isn't that big of an array, even if created from a nested list.

Comment: The type of x_training is <class 'list'> and the data of x_training is:    [[array([-1.6350065 , -0.56054485], dtype=float32), array([-1.7148849, -0.5622966], dtype=float32), array([-1.7313073 , -0.42269063], dtype=float32), array([-1.5340898, -0.6108756], dtype=float32), array([-1.56039   , -0.39346394], dtype=float32), array([0.04544015, 0.08389744], dtype=float32), [...]]]

Comment: It seems nobody has an answer to the question.